# Lack of Opportunity Queue - What's the best workaround?

Tags: opportunity, queue, sales

Salesforce does not have the functionality to assign and Opportunity to a queue. Looks like the feature has been requested and discussed a lot on Salesforce Ideas - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfoWAAS.

I have a scenario I'm working on where when an Opportunity has not been closed, or has not have any activity associated with it for sometime, it need to go into a queue, users will then have Opportunities allocated to them from the queue when they close another Opportunity (so Users have X amount of Opportunities they are working on at a time). In terms of scale, there could be 1000's of Opportunities in this queue.

In terms of workarounds, I'm thinking about creating a Salesforce User that would have these Opportunities assigned to them. My only concern doing this, is that we end up using a Salesforce license for this.

Does anyone have a better workaround to share?

Comment: To avoid burning a user license - why not just adjust the listviews for each user so disused Oppos aren't visible anymore to users by filtering on a field `Is_Disused__c` and then when a user closes an Oppo, you have a Flow that queries the is_Disused__c Oppos and assigns a new owner?